# too few arguments to function even when arguments count are correct

Tags: c, function, pointers, compiler-errors, arguments

This is the sample code:

```
typedef struct
{
  char symname[DLL_MAX_SYMNAME_LEN]; // Symbol name char
  filename[DLL_MAX_FILENAME_LEN]; // File name from which the
                                  // symbol comes
  unsigned int vaddr; // Exact address of nearest symbol
} dll_sym_info_t;

extern void sbblink_write_one_frame(u8 In,u8 F,u8 Ph,u8 Sub,u8 Ch,u8 S,u8 T, u8 P);

const char * str_sbblink_write_OP_frame_channels = "sbblink_write_one_frame";
void (*fun_sbblink_write_OP_frame_channels) (u8 In,u8 Fpga,u8 InSlot,u8 SubCh,u8 Chan,u8 Size,u8 Type,u8 Print);
.
.
fun_sbblink_write_OP_frame_channels = (void (*) (u8,u8,u8,u8,u8,u8,u8,u8))sym.vaddr;
.
.
fun_sbblink_write_OP_frame_channels (0,SBBL_FLINK,PhSlotRRH,i,0,0,0,0);
```

But even the error:

```
error: too few arguments to function 'fun_sbblink_write_OP_frame_channels'
```

Please help me with this.

THanks,

Comment: Can you provide us with the `sym`, looks like a `struct` it is!

Comment: also provide the function declaration to which `vaddr` points..

Comment: typedef struct
{
char         symname[DLL_MAX_SYMNAME_LEN];   // Symbol name
char         filename[DLL_MAX_FILENAME_LEN]; // File name from which the
                                             // symbol comes
unsigned int vaddr;                          // Exact address of nearest symbol
} dll_sym_info_t;

Comment: extern void sbblink_write_one_frame(u8 In,u8 F,u8 Ph,u8 Sub,u8 Ch,u8 S,u8 T,
            u8 P);

Comment: What is the definition of `SBBL_FLINK`?

Comment: Your code compiles just fine for me when I add a `char` token before the `filename[]` declaration inside `dll_sym_info_t` and when I provide definitions for `SBBL_FLINK`, `PhSlotRRH`, and `i`.  Are you sure you're posting your **real** code?  Can you provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: Can't you provide with all definitions of `#define`s? If you want people to help you out, then provide them with something that is compilable (except for the error that you posted for)

Answer (score 0):

Try and keep it simple.  If the "complex" problem is failing, try a simpler approach, i.e.

```
/* Since this doesn't work, let's try something that really should work
   fun_sbblink_write_OP_frame_channels (0,SBBL_FLINK,PhSlotRRH,i,0,0,0,0); */

sbblink_write_one_frame(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
```

Then, if that works try:

```
/* Since this doesn't work, let's try something that really should work
   fun_sbblink_write_OP_frame_channels (0,SBBL_FLINK,PhSlotRRH,i,0,0,0,0); */

/* OK, this worked, let's go one step forward
sbblink_write_one_frame(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8); */
fun_sbblink_write_OP_frame_channels (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
```

Then try:

```
/* OK, this silly stuff worked, let's go all the way
sbblink_write_one_frame(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
fun_sbblink_write_OP_frame_channels (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8); */
fun_sbblink_write_OP_frame_channels (0,SBBL_FLINK,PhSlotRRH,i,0,0,0,0);
```

The error/success you get in each attempt should help lead you to the problem.